# MdC Ripple keeps the class added --backgrouund focus

Tags: sass, mdc-components

I am trying to create a Button with MDC ripple effect, but somehow it is adding the class `mdc-ripple-upgraded--background-focused` and not removing it[image]

And hence the button is highlighting as grey even after the click is released.
I used this starting guide, and used this for my class syntax:

https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/
This is the what I had done:
[image: ![enter image description here]

It was a known issue in github but couldn't get a straing answer there.

Any help would be appriciated

UPdate1: I removed the class from bundle-js and its working fine for the desktop mode but not for the mobile version, its still getting selected